# Ошибка в обновлении части страницы

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, html

Отправкой через ajax пользуюсь давно, но такого не было: отправка происходит только один раз, а потом при нажатиях на div (класс .msgdel) просто перезагружает страницу.

```
$('.msgdel').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var data = "comid=" + id;
    alert(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "comdel.php",
        cache: false,
        data: data,
        success: function (html) {
            $('div#commentsdiv').load("# div#commentsdiv");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Как поправить эту строку? Без неё все в порядке. Как обновить определенный div?

```
$('div#commentsdiv').load("# div#commentsdiv");
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примере у `_POST` уходит на файл yyy.php. Но судя по структуре файла index.php,

```
<?
... [код] ...
... [Include <FORM>]...
... [Include обработчика]...
?>
```

Что-то получается адское после того, как у вас выполнится проверка и запись данных в бд, воткните функцию редара с индексом и посмотрите, что будет, методом проб и ошибок вы поймете. А еще проще просто поэкспериментируйте на голых сырцах!

Вы хедер можете кидать куда угодно, хоть на сайт мелкософта, хоть на php файл, инфу о этой функции я прикрутил в ответ! Основное, что вы должны понять в работе с header то, что он у вас правит заголовок HTTP, и к примеру ECHO и PRINT, вы не можете использовать до header'a.

Comment: @Юра Vfhfh, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно я плохо разбираюсь в js и jquery в частности, но мне не понятна конструкция:

```
 $('div#commentsdiv').load("# div#commentsdiv");
```

точней то что она должна делать.
по остальному:

1. возможен вариант что `.msgdel` находится внутри контейнера `#commentsdiv` тогда разумеется click будет сбиваться лечится это просто вместо

   ```
   $('.msgdel').click(function(){});
   ```

   используем

   ```
   $('body').delegate('.msgdel','click',function(){});
   ```
2. загрузка контента в нужный блок осуществляется в вашем случае так:

   ```
   success: function(html){$('div#commentsdiv').html(html);
   ```

Comment: К сожалению, предложенный вами способ загрузки контента не работает=(